# Did Monsanto buy and/or hire Xe/Blackwater/Academi?

Tags: commerce

I've seen a lot of posts on Facebook lately linking to various blogs and "news" sites mentioning that Monsanto purchased and/or hired Blackwater (aka Xe - search for "Monsanto Blackwater" with your favorite search engine for dozens of sites). As far as I could find, they all link to [this post](http://politicalblindspot.org/yes-monsanto-actually-did-buy-the-blackwater-mercenary-group/), which makes a lot of assumptions and has few sources to back up many of the claims (such as "Gates is also engaged in trying to destroy rural farming worldwide", etc.), however this bit (with sources) is interesting:

> [Xe (now Academi) has, indeed, been purchased](http://www.rawstory.com/rs/2010/12/17/xe-international-blackwater-sold/), and while there’s no way
>   of DOCUMENTING who the new owners really are, the logical conclusion
>   would be that Monsanto, who had been employing them prior to the sale
>   are the new owners. This, of course, would also make sense of the
>   secrecy surrounding the deal and the identity of the new owners. The
>   [company was bought out](http://www.google.com/hostednews/afp/article/ALeqM5iv14RnpjJqraPQCs5aVH9PUXN9Jw?docId=CNG.ee663915284de0064f72d69189fad44d.71) by private investors via private equity
>   companies that don’t have to divulge any of their dealings, with Bank
>   of America providing much of the [$200 million in financing](http://dealbook.nytimes.com/2010/12/16/blackwater-founder-in-deal-to-sell-company/?partner=rss&emc=rss) for the
>   deal.

[This post](http://www.democraticunderground.com/10023146763) refutes that Monsanto actually made any such acquisition, but I can't vouch for the validity of any of the sources [here](http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&key=b716156ab5ecd7182fdbf9e72d749dcb&loc=http://www.democraticunderground.com/10023146763&v=1&libId=eb4b190e-68e5-4a67-a399-dc45ef5d3eb6&out=http://www.sourcewatch.org/index.php?title=Academi#Leadership_and_Ownership&ref=https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask&title=No,%20Monsanto%20actually%20DIDN%27T%20buy%20Blackwater.%20-%20Democratic%20Underground&txt=http://www.sourcewatch.org/index.php?title=Academi#Leadership_and_Ownership&jsonp=vglnk_jsonp_13745063685547), [here](http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&key=b716156ab5ecd7182fdbf9e72d749dcb&loc=http://www.democraticunderground.com/10023146763&v=1&libId=eb4b190e-68e5-4a67-a399-dc45ef5d3eb6&out=http://redgreenandblue.org/2010/10/16/too-much-of-a-bad-thing-monsanto-did-not-buy-blackwater/&ref=https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask&title=No,%20Monsanto%20actually%20DIDN%27T%20buy%20Blackwater.%20-%20Democratic%20Underground&txt=http://redgreenandblue.org/2010/10/16/too-much-of-a-bad-thing-monsanto-did-not-buy-blackwater/&jsonp=vglnk_jsonp_13745063839508) and [here](http://www.democraticunderground.com/10023138368#post29). Otherwise, Monsanto has denied hiring them in [an 2010 article on their website](http://www.monsanto.com/newsviews/Pages/monsanto-blackwater-black-ops.aspx) which states:

> Monsanto did not hire Blackwater nor did we approve of the firm
>   infiltrating any groups as was suggested in the Nation article.

Answer (score 7):

No. Monsanto did not buy Blackwater.

The acquisition is not reported in the [2012 annual report](http://www.monsanto.com/investors/Pages/archived-annual-reports.aspx) nor in any report from [2005 to 2011](http://www.monsanto.com/investors/Pages/archived-annual-reports.aspx).

Regarding hiring, I can find no evidence that Monsanto lied when they said they did not hire them.

Comment: What about hire them?

Comment: I'm curious, did you look for any transactions with any of the shell firms created by TSI/Blackwater?

Comment: They are known to have employed the service of Blackwater/Academi mercenaries to spy on protestors and protest movements. Though there is no official report about them purchasing Academi, it does not mean that they did not. They have done illegal things before.

Comment: Also worth noting, they hired Blackwater mercenaries to act as agitators during globalisation protests.

Comment: @FerusOlin Citation needed.